# How to use alembic when applying to different databases based on environment variables?

Tags: python, flask, alembic

I am trying to use alembic and I have different databases based on the environment and it decides which databases to use.
For example stage and dev have different databases.
When I use alembic migrations in this manner same scripts under the version files are used and it returns ERROR [alembic.util.messaging] Target database is not up to date.
Is there a way to set up alembic where it will update the database schema by comparing the database and the models irrespective of existing scripts generated?

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
ERROR [alembic.util.messaging] Target database is not up to date.
```

Comment: Please share the code, what creates this error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.